# Text widget FontWeight bold property makes widget getting wider

Tags: flutter

I have a `Wrap` widget that wraps three `InkWell`. Each InkWell contains a `Text` widget. They are meant to be like TabBars to filter my ListView data. When a tab is selected, its `FontWeight` property is set to bold (w700), when it's not selected, it becomes normal weight.

Here is my code:

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 8,
                runSpacing: 8,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        color: semuaKolamBackgroundColor,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              color: semuaKolamBorderColor),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Semua",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "NotoSans", color: semuaKolamTextColor,
                            fontWeight: _selectedJenisKolam == 0 ? FontWeight.w700 : FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (_selectedJenisKolam != 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedJenisKolam = 0;
                          changeKolamType(0);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        color: kolamNormalBackgroundColor,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              width: 0.8,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              color: kolamNormalBorderColor),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Kolam Normal",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "NotoSans",
                            color: kolamNormalTextColor,
                            fontWeight: _selectedJenisKolam == 1 ? FontWeight.w700 : FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (_selectedJenisKolam != 1) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedJenisKolam = 1;
                          changeKolamType(1);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                          color: kolamKendalaBackgroundColor,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(
                                width: 0.8,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                color: kolamKendalaBorderColor),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Kolam Kendala",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "NotoSans",
                              color: kolamKendalaTextColor,
                              fontWeight: _selectedJenisKolam == 2 ? FontWeight.w700 : FontWeight.normal),
                        )),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (_selectedJenisKolam != 2) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedJenisKolam = 2;
                          changeKolamType(2);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Problem is whenever I move from first tab `Semua` to other tab, the first tab width size is getting decreased (wrap content).

Example:
Before: [image: Semua tab]

After: [image: Kolam Kendala tab]

It is not clear to see with screenshots. But what actually happening is `Kolam Normal` tab moved a little to left because `Semua` tab is getting smaller.

Comment: What are doing inside `changeKolamType()` I'm running without it, and failed to reproduce the errors, can provide a sample widget that will produce the same kind of issue you are facing?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added screenshots

Comment: The FontWeight property is used to make the text a litter wider then the original text. So its true that you are looking.

Comment: @RakeshSaini That is my problem. I dont want the ```Container``` width decreases everytime I move out from the tab. It makes UI ugly.

Comment: You can provide the fixed widths for container.

Comment: @RakeshSaini I thought of this too but i thought there might be other solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires you to specify a `width` to your `Container`. But as you probably want a way where the `Container` always follows the length of text, the code below will solve your issue.

The solution requires you to use the `TextPainter` to calculate the width that the text would require post build, and we use the style of the higher fontWeight to take the max width and make a constant for both weights (as seen in the style provided to the `span` in the `LayoutBuilder`). To use this calculated value almost immediately, we use the `LayoutBuilder`

Also its not good practice to repeat similar widgets as you've done in your question, but instead to create a function to reproduce them with different variables (also shown in code)

```
Widget returnNewThing() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 8,
        runSpacing: 8,
        children: [
          // add the colors and other params into the method if needed
          createInkWell(buttonText: 'Semua', currentIndex: 0),
          createInkWell(buttonText: 'Kolam Normal', currentIndex: 1),
          createInkWell(buttonText: 'Kolam Kendala', currentIndex: 2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  InkWell createInkWell(
      {Color shapeColor = kolanNormalBackgroundColor,
      Color borderColor = kolanNormalBorderColor,
      required String buttonText,
      required int currentIndex,
      Color textColor = kolamNormalTextColor}) {
    return InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
        final span = TextSpan(text: buttonText, style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "NotoSans",
            color: textColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700));
        final tp = TextPainter(
            text: span,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            maxLines: 1)
          ..layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);
        var widthNeeded = tp.width; //may need to add some padding i.e. + 4
        
        return Container(
          width: widthNeeded,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: shapeColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                  width: 0.8, style: BorderStyle.solid, color: borderColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            buttonText,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "NotoSans",
                color: textColor,
                fontWeight: _selectedJenisKolam == currentIndex
                    ? FontWeight.w700
                    : FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        );
      }), 
      onTap: () {
        if (_selectedJenisKolam != currentIndex) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedJenisKolam = currentIndex;
            changeKolamType(currentIndex);
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This seems legit and thank you for the advice of using functions to build widgets. Thank you!